# Get data from file created by nwjs

Tags: node.js, windows, file, data-extraction, nwjs

I would like to extract real-time data from a file that does not have a .

this file is a history of an application developed with nwjs

file example:

[image]

do you have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be an SQLite database file. This question has nothing to do with NW.js and is poorly worded.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [Better SQLite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3). There are instructions for how to set it up there.